# Joomla ACl problems

Tags: joomla, components, acl

I've written a component for Joomla 2.5.  It works great.  However I'm having access control issues.  The component manages documents.  It allows clients to upload them, tag them, search etc.  All this works fine.  The user needs to be looged in to the system to be able to view, edit and delete documents.

Unfortunately whilst the system restricts editing and deleting it doesn't seem to restrict viewing.  It doesn't restrict the view to logged in users only.  If you type the component url for a document directly into the browser bar it loads up the view:

http://www.mydomain.com/component/document_managment/1.html?view=document

I've searched around and can't find anything that helps.  Any ideas about what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you already have a complete ACL implemented, i.e. there is an asset column in the `documents` table, and you have an `access.xml` with some ACL rules defined i.e.

```
<section name="component">
  <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
...
```

1. You want to add `core.view` and `core.view.own` ACL rules in the `access.xml` (which is typically in your administrator-component root).

   ```
   <action name="core.view" title="View all documents"
   <action name="core.view.own" title="View own documents"
   ```
2. In the component configuration, assign privileges to the users so super users can view all (managers have `core.view` privilege) and every registered user has `core.view.own`
3. In the view.html or -even better- in the model, you test for the privileges before loading any data:

   ```
   $user = JFactory::getUser();
   $id = $app->input->getInt('id') // load the document id
   $canView = false;
   if($id){
       $canView = $user->authorise('core.view', 'com_yourcomponent.document') || 
           $user->authorise('core.view.own', 'com_yourcomponent.document.'.$id);
   }
   ```

Comment: hi @RiccardoZorn thanks for the help.  I can't get it to work properly.  It now bans viewing the doc but it also stops anyone who is logged in viewing the doc.  I don't have an asset column in the documents table. Why is is needed?  The edit etc works without it.  Thanks

Comment: If you don't have it, most likely any user with edit privileges can edit any documents; while usually you want to allow only the owner and super users to edit; ACLs allow you to achieve this, but you need an asset per each document, hence the asset column I mentioned.

Comment: Of course, you could achieve the same just checking the user "general" permissions (core.view & core.edit) and the document's owner id; but you would manually write code to achieve what Joomla!'s ACL already offer you.